# Archive tvOS app

Tags: xcode, tvos

I am trying to archive my tvOS app to submit it to the App Store. But I have an error:
[image: Error image]
I don't understand what is the problem because I have a valid Developer Account and I checked the case "Automatically manage signing".

I also tried to create a tvOS provisioning profile for my app but it doesn't work.

Note: I have an iOS version of my app, which is already on the App Store and I created the tvOS app as a new target, but it seems not to work in a new project.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Uncheck "Automatically manage signing" and then enable it again.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest Solution for you is to Uncheck "Automatically Manage Signing" and go to developer site and create a provisioning profile with your apps bundle id and download it and add it to Xcode. Then it will stop complaining for the second one.

When you achieve select "Generic tvOS Device"as target device then it will stop complaining for the first one.

If you have time then watch Whats new in App Signing video of wwdc 2016 - https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/401/ , it has more info on how to debug when these kind of error occur.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I have now another error, it says: "Provisioning profile "xxxxxxxx" doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Developer: xxxxx (---------)".". I'll watch the video

Comment: When you generate a provisioning profile you can choose which of the ceritificates include that provisioning profile. If you add it to the one you are using it should just work fine.

Comment: I have only one certificate so I selected that one but it doesn't work